# OpenCVで車種を判別する方法について

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi

OpenCVの初心者です. OpenCVを使って画像の色の変換や二値化反転などの処理はできるのですが, 車種(普通車やトラックなど)の判別の仕方が分かりません. 具体的にどのような手法があるのか教えてください.

Answer (score 1):

一般的には機械学習、ディープラーニング等を使って車種判別を行うと思います。
詳しくは下記を参照してください。
https://qiita.com/icoxfog417/items/53e61496ad980c41a08e

Comment: コメントありがとうございます. 機械学習やディープラーニングを使わずに車種判別を行う方法はありますか？

Comment: 簡単な方法は、輪郭を抽出して、その形、面積等で判別する方法だと思います。